# $emit data not accesable in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to send a data from the service to the controller with $emit. Whenever I am console.log in the service the data is there, but in the controller $rootScope.$on I don't see the data.

```
service.GetTest = function () {
    var inside = this;
    var promise = $http(
    {
        method: 'POST',
        url: inside.baseUrl + 'Admin/setTest',
        contentType: 'application/json'
    });
    promise.then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $rootScope.$emit('monitor', data);
    })
}

$rootScope.$on('monitor', function (event,data) {
        console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: After your modifications in your code, this is work on to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$on`'s call back has the `event` first. Your function should be `function(event, data)`, not `function(data)`.

Also, you should consider returning the promise from `GetTest`. It sounds like a resource method that should promise chain instead of using an event.